# Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I am trying to have a useRef obj to be either null or a function
here is code snippet

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const testRef = useRef<string | null>(null);
  const unblockRef = useRef<() => void | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const test = () => {
      console.log("hey");
    };

    testRef.current = "";

    // this would give the error code
    unblockRef.current = null;
    // unblockRef.current = "saddsa";
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is [playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-fast-gjfi1b?file=/src/App.tsx:0-537), from other stack overflow post, it seems like i just need to pass null type when we initialize the useRef obj.

I test the logic with testRef, which works fine, it seems like if the useRef type is function that would give trouble,  Thanks for any kinds of help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's simply a TypeScript error. Your syntax is problematic:

```js
const unblockRef = useRef<() => void | null>(null);
```

This is interpreted as *a function that returns either void or null*.

So, you need to make sure it's a *function or null*:

```js
const unblockRef = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);
```

Answer (score 16):

There are two types of ref : mutable or inmutable

```
React.RefObject
React.MutableRefObject
```

your sintax for testRef works ( *| null* ) is the key...

```
  const testRef = useRef<string | null>(null);
```

this way you implicit create a React.MutableRefObject and can assign

```
testRef.current = "some string";
```

in the other case unblockRef is only React.RefObject due to incorrect sintax as the other answers says. You must use parentesis due to operators precedence.

```
const unblockRef = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);
```

Anyway an explicit declaration could also be used:

```
const testRef:React.MutableRefObject<string | null> = useRef<string | null>(null);

const unblockRef:React.MutableRefObject<(() => void)| null> = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);
```

[here there is a very good explanation article](https://dev.to/wojciechmatuszewski/mutable-and-immutable-useref-semantics-with-react-typescript-30c9#mutable-raw-current-endraw-property)

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is how you are using the `|` operator. Namely, the precedence for this type:

```
() => void | null
```

is actually

```
() => (void | null)
```

If you add some explicit parens to make the type

```
const unblockRef = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);
```

then you are able to reassign it.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning *multiple* types to a variable, if one of those types is a callback, you *must* wrap the callback in its own set of parenthesis.

```
const unblockRef = useRef<(() => void) | null>(null);
```

This is because you can return multiple types from a function. So, logically, TypeScript thinks your function will return either `void` or `null` - as opposed to *just* void.